# Postfix - mixing virtual_aliases and virtual_mailboxes (catchall)

Tags: postfix

I'm running postfix (2.9.6) with dovecot (2.2.5) and I two domains:

1. example.com as a virtual_mailbox_domain
2. example.org as a virtual_alias_domain

I'd like to set up two different catch-all rules for unknown users but it does not work as expected.

Using the configuration below the catch-all rule for example.com applies to both example.com and example.org addresses (i.e. all unkown mail is delivered to johndoe's catch_com mailbox, regardless of example.org or example.com addresses). Removing the @example.com rule causes the @example.org rule to work propperly (mail delivered to johndoe's catch_org mailbox).

main.cf:

```
recipient_delimiter = +

virtual_mailbox_domains = example.com
virtual_mailbox_maps = hash:/opt/local/etc/postfix/virtual_mailbox

virtual_alias_domains = example.org
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/opt/local/etc/postfix/virtual_alias
```

master.cf

```
dovecot   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=DRhu user=vmail:vmail argv=/opt/local/libexec/dovecot/dovecot-lda -f ${sender} -d ${user}@${nexthop} -m ${extension}
```

virtual_mailbox:

```
johndoe@example.com         example.com/johndoe
```

virtual_alias:

```
@example.org            johndoe+catch_org@example.com
@example.com            johndoe+catch_com@example.com
```

Adding the catchall rule to virtual_mailbox does not work because as I have read somewhere using dovecot-lda causes catchall rules in the virtual_mailbox to be ignored.

Answer (score 3):

This is expected behavior from postfix. Virtual Alias will be checked first before any other alias. So the catchall of example.com `/opt/local/etc/postfix/virtual_alias` will routes your email before `/opt/local/etc/postfix/virtual_mailbox`.

**In your case `johndoe+catch_org` will recursively mapped to `virtual_alias` again so it will matched with `johndoe+catch_com`.**

If you setup catchall to another mailbox in same domain, then you can setup catchall in `virtual_mailbox_maps`. Add this line in bottom of `/opt/local/etc/postfix/virtual_mailbox`

```
@example.com    example.com/johndoe
```

The downside is you can't differentiate the email between example.com catchall or example.org catchall. *For dovecot case, I can't confirm this scheme will work or not.*

---

Another ugly solution is put the non-catchall account of example.com in `/opt/local/etc/postfix/virtual_alias`. For example:

```
# account with mailbox
john@example.com        john@example.com
doee@example.com        doee@example.com
abcd@example.com        abcd@example.com

# for example.org domain catch all
johndoe+catch_org@example.com     johndoe+catch_org@example.com 

@example.org            johndoe+catch_org@example.com
@example.com            johndoe+catch_com@example.com
```